# Regex to get text from within parenthesis including delimited parenthsis

Tags: regex, powershell

I am using powershell, if that matters.

Let's say I have

```
$s = "One two (three) four \(five\) six (\(seven\)) eight"
```

I want a regex that will return

```
 three
 (seven)
```

I need all matches, and I know how PowerShell stores the matches in $matches, similar to perl's $1 $2 $3 (but that's the easy part).

Comment: i think you want `three` and `\(seven\)`

Comment: Actually, I need three and (seven), but that is easy because I can handle that with a simple replace() function when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below regex and get the string you want from group index 1.

```
(?<!\\)\(((?:\\[()]|[^()])*)\)
```

Negative lookbehind `(?<!\\)` which asserts that the match wouldn't be preceded by `\` symbol.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/kT6vO6/2)

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<!\\)\(([^)]+\))
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/kT6vO6/3